# Resuming an application from sleep causes 'Communications link failure'

Tags: mysql, timeout, connection-pooling, cloudbees

I have a CloudBees Run@cloud instance configured that runs fine, but after a while of inactivity it gets de-activated, and then seems the connection pool is not properly refreshed.

When I return to the site, the first few requests time out with:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 4,746,680 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor86.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3092)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2978)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3526)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5022)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:87)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
```

I am connecting via JNDI using a datasource configured in the cloudbees-web.xml file as such:

```
    <resource name="jdbc/myapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <param name="username" value="myuser" />
        <param name="password" value="mypass" />
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:cloudbees://myurl />
    </resource>
```

Is there some configuration I'm missing, or is this a bug with the connection pool configuration in the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[From the [Database Guide](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide) on the CloudBees Wiki]*

MySQL includes a timeout that will close connections that have been idle for long periods of time. For improved Database performance, CloudBees DataSources use the Apache DBCP connection pool to reuse JDBC connections after they are closed by the application.

If you use a connection that has been in the pool idle for too long, your application will likely experience the following error: "The last packet successfully received from the server was XXX seconds ago".

The connection pool includes a setting the will validate and throw out dead connections when calling javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(). To use this setting, add the following XML params to your DataSource definition in cloudbees-web.xml.

```
<param name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
<param name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
```

So for your resource, you should be able to do the following:

```
<resource name="jdbc/myapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <param name="username" value="myuser" />
    <param name="password" value="mypass" />
    <param name="url" value="jdbc:cloudbees://myurl />
    <param name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <param name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</resource>
```

If you are using the bees app:bind command instead of cloudbees-web.xml to inject your datasources, you can use these params as arguments to the command

```
bees app:bind -a APP_ID -db DB_NAME -as JNDI_ALIAS validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow=true
```

Comment: Be aware that testOnBorrow will cause SELECT 1 being performed EVERY time a connection is grabbed from the pool, e.g. practically for every executed query. Evicting connections after a certain timeout using minEvictableIdleTimeMillis, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis and numTestsPerEviction as described here http://juststuffreally.blogspot.de/2007/10/broken-pipes-with-tomcat-and-dbcp.html might be a better idea for DBCP pool. Alternatively you might try testWhileIdle instead of testOnBorrow.